# my list doesn't move on the right side of the page

Tags: html, css

I'm having a problem on my page. Since I embedded a google form on my page the text doesn't move where I want to (which is right ->)

```css
.inform {
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<section id="iform">
  <iframe src="https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLScZuujO3RzMA9N6nkGJ2Pl50m0SigWE2j1H_-WmODd2bE5-jw/viewform?embedded=true" width="600" height="760" frameborder="3" marginheight="0" marginwidth="5">Loading...</iframe>
  <div class="inform">
    <ul>
      <li>Fill all the required information.</li>
      <li> Within a hour/day, an invoice reply email should sent to you </li>
      <li> After the preview of your logo has been sent to your email, The payment link will be sent with the preview of your logo</li>
      <li> after the payment has been received, the original copy will be sent to your email.</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Not sure if I'm misinterpreting your question but I can see the text aligned to the right perfectly for me. See [screenshot](https://puu.sh/vMht5/623332db3d.png) or [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/p88mpg5h/)

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you meant?

https://jsfiddle.net/ChefGabe/w5v8ar0q/

In that case I just added:

```
#iform {
    display: flex;
}
```

Comment: i did copy the code but here what happens: https://snag.gy/UBWN71.jpg

i think its the browser?

Comment: @AegirAideron Is it possible you have some extra CSS or HTML on that webpage? I can only see part of the page. I doubt it's the browser (unless it's IE)

Comment: i have 3 pages and 3 individual css so its more easy to behave...
edit: its the same on firefox, IE, chrome... :(

Comment: @AegirAideron Ok but I still can't debug your code if I can't see all of it.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/ChefGabe/zha4dhuh/ I pasted your code into a JSfiddle and commented out the `display:flex` because it screwed up the page. Can you tell me what's wrong with that page? Feel free to fork the JSFiddle.

Comment: i just want to move the list on the right side of the form not underneath the form.

Comment: nvm, i just turned into img and it work :D thx for the effort anyway.. :D

Answer (score 0):

What exactly are you looking for?

Your code will display like this.

```
________
|      |
| form |
|______|

 -       List item
 -          item 2
```

If you want it to appear like this

```
________
|      |     - List item
| form |     - item 2
|______|
```

You can use

```
.inform {
    float: right;
    max-width: 400px; /* so we wrap the list for smaller width screen */
}
```